# Calculation based on formula between two panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames having almost identical row and index.
df1:

```
Product AU-1    AU-2    AU-3
PROD1   5       7       8
PROD2   4       7       2
PROD3   2       60      7
```

df2:

```
Product AU-1    AU-2    AU-3
PROD1   100     200     111
PROD2   757     7575    908
common  10      20      30
PROD3   656     657     6565
```

Output I want to get:

```
Product AU-1    AU-2    AU-3
PROD1   100.5   201.4   113.4
PROD2   757.4   7576.4  908.6
common  0       0       0
PROD3   656.2   669     6567.1
```

formulae for each cell :

```
each cell value of df2 + (corresponding "common" value * corresponding df1 value/100)
```

Example for PROD1 and AU-1

```
100 + (5*10/100) = 100.5
```

How can I do that in most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Product` is not currently an index, make it one, so that you can get index alignment when you multiply, and from there, implementing your formula is trivial.

---

```
df1, df2 = (d.set_index('Product') for d in (df1, df2))

df2.add(df1.mul(df2.loc['common']).div(100)).fillna(0)
```

```
          AU-1    AU-2    AU-3
Product
PROD1    100.5   201.4   113.4
PROD2    757.4  7576.4   908.6
PROD3    656.2   669.0  6567.1
common     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: "Product" is df2 is actually an index @user3483203 . df2 is a pivot table:df2 = pd.pivot_table(df_temp,values="cost",index = "product", columns="account",fill_value=0)

Comment: You should only have to `set_index` for `df1` then.

Comment: yes I did that, but getting an error: "'generator' object has no attribute 'mul'"

Comment: You probably didn't take the parenthesis out of the `set_index` line.  Just use `df1 = df1.set_index('Product')`

Comment: Does your pivot table not have a row called `common`?  Can you update your question with your actual dataframes?

Comment: one question.Say for example I don't want for one particular row(index = PROD3) to be involved int his calculation, say for example "PROD3" would be same as it was, no calculation. How I can exclude one particular index from calculation

Comment: You could create a mask that only contains valid indices and then use `df2.loc[...].add(...)`